# Changing resources in a Symfony website without having to refresh the browser cache

Tags: symfony-1.4, browser-cache

I have a Symfony 1.4 website with content (images, js, and css). Sometimes, I update the website, so thoses files are changed. Then I push the changes to the server, but the changes are not visible in a browser because the browser is caching thoses files.

What is the best way that the end user see the changes that are made in maximum 1 day time ?
I have tought about setting the cache duration to 24hours for all elements. How can I do that in Symfony ?

Answer (score 1):

Client-side caching is discussed at http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/12-Caching#chapter_12_http_1_1_and_client_side_caching

If that doesn't answer your questions, can you add the HTTP response headers to your question?